# Array variable name changes from readings1 to readings2

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, button, array

I've been using two MB1240 Ultrasonic Sensors with analogRead, and have found that after using bubble sort, the array is found in array readings2, and not readings1. This is important because I would like to find the distance from each sensor.

Below is the code I've put together that uses buttons to determine when each sensor should be triggered.

```
const int anPin1 = 1;
const int anPin2 = 2;

const int triggerPin = 2;
long anVolt1, anVolt2;

// button Pins
const int buttonPin1 = 11;
const int buttonPin2 = 13;

int buttonState1;
int buttonState2;
int lastButtonState1 = false;
int lastButtonState2 = false;

long lastDebounceTime1 = 0;
long lastDebounceTime2 = 0;
long debounceDelay = 50; //ms

// initialise averaging array
const int numberOfReadings = 10; // reasonable DOF
long readings1[numberOfReadings];
long readings2[numberOfReadings];
long median;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(triggerPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  delay(200); // Datasheet: Sensors require 175 ms to calibrate
}

void start_sensor(){
  digitalWrite(triggerPin,HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin,LOW);
}

long read_sensor1(){
  //Used to read in the analog voltage output that is being sent by the XL-MaxSonar device.
  //Scale factor is (Vcc/1024) per centimeter. A 5V supply yields ~4.9mV/cm for standard range sensors
  anVolt1 = analogRead(anPin1);
  return anVolt1;
}

long read_sensor2(){
  anVolt2 = analogRead(anPin2);
  return anVolt2;
}

void printall(long readings[]) {
  int med = numberOfReadings/2;
  median = (readings[med-1] + readings[med])/2;  

  Serial.print("Sensor: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadings; i++) {
    Serial.print(readings[i]);
    Serial.print("cm ");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Median: ");
  Serial.print(median);
  Serial.println(" cm");
}

void loop () {
  int reading1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
  int reading2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  // for noise
  if (reading1 != lastButtonState1) {
    lastDebounceTime1 = millis();
  }

  // for noise
  if (reading2 != lastButtonState2) {
    lastDebounceTime2 = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime1) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading1 != buttonState1) {
      buttonState1 = reading1;
      if (buttonState1 == HIGH) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadings; i++){
         start_sensor();
          readings1[i] = read_sensor1();
          delay(150); // From datasheet: Period = 99ms
        }

            **// bubble sort with flag
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(readings1)-1; i++) {
            bool flag = true;
            for (int j = 1; j < sizeof(readings1)-1; j++) {
                if (readings1[j-1] > readings1[j]) {
                    int t = readings1[j-1];
                    readings1[j-1] = readings1[j];
                    readings1[j] = t;
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag) break;
        }
       printall(readings1);**
      }
    }
  }

  lastButtonState1 = reading1; 

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime2) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading2 != buttonState2) {
      buttonState2 = reading2;
      if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadings; i++) {
          start_sensor();
          readings2[i] = read_sensor2();
          delay(150);   
        }
       printall(readings2);
      }
    }
  }
  lastButtonState2 = reading2;

  //clear previous readings
  memset(readings1, 0, sizeof(readings1));
  memset(readings2, 0, sizeof(readings2));
}
```

Scenario: I have clicked the first button to return a reading from the first sensor, and I am expecting the results to be stored then sorted in array readings1. After the bubble sort, if I enter printall(readings1), it returns an array of zeros, but if I use a printall(readings2), it returns the sorted array I expected.

I can't find where I'm going wrong with this one, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't using `qsort` be easier, faster, and more reliable?

Comment: `qsort` is brilliant. I switched from a bubble sort to a qsort algorithm for ordering triangles in a 3d mesh drawing library and it went from ~1fps for 8000 triangles to ~20fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> for (int j = 1; j < sizeof(readings1)-1; j++) {
> ```

`sizeof(readings1)` is **not** the number of elements in the array, it is the size of the array in bytes (in your case, 40). You are exceeding the bounds of the array. You know the number of items (`numberOfReadings`) - why not use that?